# getting actual column types from SPSiteDataQuery

Tags: sharepoint-2010, datatable, column-types, spsitedataquery

I'm trying to query a site collection for documents of a certain user
the query works fine, but the columns in datatable returned are all string columns,
and when you try to sort a column which represents a number - the sort result
is wrong.

is there a way to get the datatable with actual columns type?

Comment: When you create a DataTable with DataColumn , you can specify DataType. Example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype.aspx

Comment: well... I already know that.. and it doesn't answer my question.. ( i want to avoid converting every item in every line in the returned datatable to its original type)